# Draw the image using opencv at Qt

Tags: c++, qt, opencv

Environment: Qt Creator 4.0.3 (Qt5.7.0/MSVC2013 x64)
             Windows 10 pro

I want to draw the image using opencv.
so I write the code. then compile(msvc2013 x64) the project.
but release mode do not execution.
(Application Output: ..\Qt_5_7_0_MSVC2013_64bit-Release\release\QtNavi.exe exited with code 255)

So I installed winDebug package for debuging.
and "The program has unexpectedly finished."

What is wrong?

--sample source--

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QImage>
#include <QLayout>
#include <opencv2\opencv.hpp>

void ShowImage(QImage* qsrc, cv::Mat* msrc);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QWidget *w = new QWidget;

    cv::Mat img = cv::imread("C:/Users/BYEONGGIL/Pictures/lena.jpg");

    // code 1 
    QLabel* display1 = new QLabel;
    QImage* QImg1 = new QImage;
    ShowImage(QImg1, &img);
    display1->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(*QImg1));

    // code 2
    QLabel* display2 = new QLabel;
    cv::Mat tmp = img.clone();
    cv::cvtColor(tmp, tmp, CV_BGR2RGB);
    QImage qImg2((unsigned char*)tmp.data, tmp.cols, tmp.rows, tmp.step, QImage::Format_RGB888);
    display2->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(qImg2));

    //
    QGridLayout* layout = new QGridLayout;
    layout->addWidget(display1,0,0);
    layout->addWidget(display2,0,1);
    w->setLayout(layout);
    w->show();

    return a.exec();
}

void ShowImage(QImage* qsrc, cv::Mat* msrc)
{
    cv::Mat tmp = msrc->clone();
    cv::cvtColor(tmp, tmp, CV_BGR2RGB);
    *qsrc = QImage((unsigned char*)tmp.data, tmp.cols, tmp.rows, tmp.step, QImage::Format_RGB888);

    return;
}
```

Comment: However, to use the QImage, GUI is required.

Comment: Not really, you can save it and look at with image viewer (Qt GUI module is still needed in the project I think, but you don't have to show any GUI, is what I mean). But the point is to have an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so it is irrelevant if you actually see the image.

Comment: Also, your GUI can be just a single top level QLabel which you show() before calling exec(), that's probably most convenient.

Comment: Btw. In your question code, note that display1 is a top level window (no parent), and you never show it, so you wouldn't see your image even if the program didn't crash.

Comment: I edit my code without GUI.
code 1 is what I want, but is not operating.
but code 2 is operating

Comment: If it builds, but crashes when run, I would suspect library problem. Try copying OpenCV DLL to same folder with .exe by hand.

Comment: Oh, that construction of QImage from temp variable in ShowImage looks a bit suspicious. You may be creating QImage from local data, which goes out of scope earlier than QImage expects. Check the docs of the constructor and OpenCV clone(), if they say if you use them right.